Invariance of creation and annihilation operators under mode transformation

In exercise1.4 of "Introduction to Optical Quantum Information Processing",
the commutation relations for the mode operators is preserved under mode function transformation.Where,$\hat{b}_{\lambda'}(\kappa)$ is defined below.

$\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{k})$ is unit vectors orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{k}$.
$v$ is a translated mode function and $(\phi,\psi)$ is the "time-independent scalar product" defined by


$\hat{a}_{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{k})$ satisfies the following commutation relations.

However, I can't understand this claim.
It is too difficult for me to calculate scalar product of polarization vectors.
Is this claim true?
Also, please let me know if there are any reference books that explain a mode translation of free scalar fields.

Hello and welcome to PSE. Consider writing explicitly the formulas you wish us to see. Cheers

You might find it easier start with a simpler finite dimensional example and gradually connect it to the question that you shared.
Let's suppose that you have a finite set of creation/annihilation operators $\hat a_i$, $\hat a_i^\dagger$ that satisfy the commutation relation $[\hat a_i, \hat a^\dagger_j] = \delta_{ij}$, $1\leq i,j\leq N$.  You can think of this algebra as being associated with an $N$-dimensional harmonic oscillator.  Let's say you introduce a new set of operators $\hat b_\ell=\sum_{i}(\alpha^{(\ell)}_ia_i + \beta_i ^{(\ell)} a^\dagger_i)$ where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are independent sets of coefficients (so $\hat b^\dagger= \sum_i (\bar \alpha a_i^\dagger + \bar\beta_ia_i)$.)  Under what conditions (i.e. for what values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$) do $\hat b_\ell$ and $\hat b^\dagger_k$ satisfy the original commutation relations?
\begin{align*}
[\hat b_i,\hat b^\dagger_\ell] &= \Big[\sum_j\big(\alpha_j^{(i)} a_j+\beta_j^{(i)}a_j^\dagger\big), \sum_{j'}\big(\bar\alpha_{j'}^{(\ell)}a^\dagger_{j'}+\bar\beta^{(\ell)}_{j'}a_{j'}\big)\Big]\\
& = \sum_{j,j'}\Big(\alpha_j\bar\alpha_{j'}[a_j,a^\dagger_{j'}] + \beta_j\bar\beta_{j'}[a_j^\dagger,a_{j'}]\Big),\quad ([a_j',a_j] = [a^\dagger_{j'},a_j^\dagger] = 0)\\
&=\sum_{j,j'}\Big(\alpha_j\bar\alpha_{j'}\delta_{j,j'}- \beta_j\bar \beta_{j'}\delta_{j,j'}\Big)\\
&= \langle \alpha^{(\ell)},\alpha^{(i)}\rangle - \langle\beta^{(\ell)},\beta^{(i)}\rangle.
\end{align*}
($i$ and $\ell$ indices suppressed in second and third lines for ease of typing.)
Hence, it seems that in order for the new set of operators to satisfy the original commutation relations the $2N$-dimensional vectors $(\alpha,\beta)^{(i)}$ need to be orthonormal with respect to an inner product of the form $\big((\alpha, \beta), (\gamma, \delta)\big) \equiv \langle\alpha,\gamma\rangle - \langle \beta, \delta\rangle$, where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the "ordinary" complex dot product.  Mathematically, transformations from $\hat a$ to $\hat b$ would then correspond to elements of the group $SU(N, N)$, complex matrices that preserve the 'metric' with $N$ positive 1's and $N$ negative 1's on the diagonal (and zero elsewhere.)
Now to connect with your question, we need a vector space to associate with the creation and annihilation operators (analogous to the function space that you refer to), so that each creation and annihilation operator is associated with its own basis function.  Let's call these basis vectors $e_i$ and $f_i$, and suppose there is a natural inner product where $\langle e_i, f_j\rangle = 0$ and $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle = \langle f_i, f_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$.  If we associate these basis functions with $a_i$ and $a_i^\dagger$, there is a natural correspondence between $e_i$ and $f_i$, which induces a map from the $e$ subspace to the $f$ subspace analogous to complex conjugation, and this correspondence $C$ can be completed by anti-linearity in the $e$ basis. We would like to see if it's possible generate a new set of operators $b_i$ so that the transformation from $a_i$ to $b_i$ is induced by a transformation of the $e$ and $f$ bases. As a simple example, $e$ and $f$ might represent Fourier modes on a discrete segment with positive and negative frequency, in which case $C$ is simply complex conjugation. Let's suppose that $e'$ and $f'$ are a new basis, where $f'=Ce'$ (this is for consistency with $v^*$ being the complex conjugate of $v$.)
In your question, the $b$ operators are defined in terms of the projection of $v$ functions to the $u$ and $u^*$ basis (with a special dot product.)  The finite-dimensional analog of this is to project the $e'$ functions to the $e$ and $f$ basis, with an appropriate generalization of the special dot product. That is, $b_\ell = \sum_i\big[(e_\ell', e_i)a_i + (e_\ell',f_i)a^\dagger_i\big]$, $b_\ell^\dagger = \sum_i\big[(f_\ell',e_i)a_i + (f_\ell', f_i)a^\dagger_i\big]$, and it remains how $(\cdot,\cdot)$ should be understood in order for $b$ and $b^\dagger$ to satisfy the original commutation rules.  For consistency with Hermitian conjugation (i.e. so that $b^\dagger$ actually equals $(b)^\dagger$), it must be the case that $(f_\ell', f_i)$ equals $\overline{(e_\ell', e_i)}$, and $(f_\ell', e_i)$ equals $\overline{(e_\ell', f_i)}$.  From the first result, we have
\begin{align*}
[\hat b_\ell, \hat b_{\ell'}^\dagger] &= \langle \overline{(f_{\ell'}', f)}, (e_\ell', e)\rangle - \langle \overline{(f_{\ell'}', e)}, (e_\ell', f)\rangle\\
&=\langle (e_{\ell'}', e), (e_\ell', e)\rangle - \langle (e_{\ell'}', f), (e_\ell', f)\rangle
\end{align*}
Hence, the components of $e_\ell'$ contribute differently to the commutator depending on whether they are in the '$e$' or '$f$' subspaces (corresponding to 'positive' or 'negative' frequencies, respectively.)  Moreover, letting $\ell=\ell'$, we have $[b_\ell, b_{\ell}^\dagger] = \|(e_{\ell}', e)\|^2 - \|(e_\ell', f)\|^2$, which is only $1$ if $e_\ell'$ is appropriately normalized with respect to $e$ and $f$.  Hence, it might be worth paying closer attention to the form of $v(\kappa;r,t)$ and the normalization condition in particular (which would also be relevant to orthogonality.)  If $e_\ell'$ is normalized in the above inner product (where the "negative" frequency $L^2$ norm is subtracted from "positive" frequency $L^2$ norm), then the new operators $b_i$ would satisfy the original commutation relations and you would be done. So let's see if we can find a connection between the "time independent" inner product and the quadratic form we wrote down above.
Note that if $\phi(x,t) = \int\frac{dk}{(2\pi)^d} (\phi_+(k)e^{i\omega(k)t} + \phi_-(k)e^{-i\omega(k)t})e^{k\cdot x}$, the time independent inner product is given by
\begin{align*}
(\phi,\psi)&=i\int dr\Big(\phi^*\partial_t\psi - \partial_t\phi^*\psi\Big)\\
&= \vdots \\
&= 2\int\frac{dk}{(2\pi)^d}\omega(k)(\phi_+^*(k)\psi_+(k) - \phi_-^*(k)\psi_-(k))
\end{align*}
which you may notice looks conspicuously similar to the dot product derived earlier... (at least, modulo a factor of $2\omega(k)$, which might be connected to the normalization of basis functions.)
Now, to account for polarization components, simply add a second index $\lambda$ to the $a$ and $b$ operators and their corresponding vectors/modes, and extend the dot product by summing over these indices as well.  The dot product doesn't need to be modified from the original $SU(n)$ dot product because the individual mode polarization vectors that appear in sums over $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are multiplied by either $a$ or $a^\dagger$ operators, but not both (i.e. you might see a term of the form $(e_{\ell'}',e_\ell)\sum_\lambda \beta_\lambda a_\lambda e_\ell$ or $(e_{\ell'}',e_\ell^*)\sum_\lambda \beta_\lambda' a_\lambda^\dagger e_\ell^*$, but never, e.g., $(e_{\ell'}',e_\ell)\big(\beta_{-1}a_{-1} + \beta_{1} a^\dagger_1\big)$.)
In theory, the polarization components simply multiply the dimensionality of the $e$ and $f$ subspaces (by the dimensionality of the polarization vector space), and thereby allow a much much larger space of commutator-preserving transformations (i.e. from $SU(N,N)$ to $SU(dN, dN)$, where $d$ is the dimensionality of $\epsilon_\ell$.)  For physical reasons, however, it usually makes more sense to consider a smaller set of transformations: $SU(d)_e^N\times SU(d)_f^N\times SU(N,N)$, or even $SU(d)^N\times SU(N,N)$ (where the each copy of $SU(d)$ is identified as a diagonal or anti-diagonal subgroup of $SU(d)_e\times SU(d)_f$).  In any case, the transformation of $(e_\ell\epsilon_{\ell},f_{\ell'}\epsilon_{\ell'})$ is some unitary operator over the components: the set of mathematically allowable transformations that preserve the commutator structure is typically much much larger than the set of transformations (symmetries) that are relevant to a particular physical model.
In your example, the polarizations $\mathbf \epsilon_\lambda(\mathbf k)$ live in two-dimensional vector subspaces $V_{\mathbf{k}} \equiv \{\mathbf k'| \mathbf k'\cdot \mathbf k = 0\}$, and the polarizations $\mathbf\epsilon'_\lambda(\mathbf k)$ for the $b$ operators can be chosen to be completely different bases for $V_{\mathbf{k}}$, $\mathbf{k}\in\mathbb R^3$. This gives you enormous freedom in choosing $\mathbf{\epsilon}_\lambda'(\kappa)$: all that matters is $\mathbf{\epsilon}_\lambda'(\mathbf \kappa)\cdot \mathbf\kappa = 0$, $\lambda = 1, 2$.  This description (in terms of $V_\mathbf k$ subspaces) would be a little bit questionable if Poincare or Lorentz transformations were involved, but in that case you would probably express the polarization directly in terms of photon states (whose polarizations would be defined to transform covariantly in terms of the [gauged] little group $U(1)$ or $SO(2)$.)

Thank you for your reply. I can't understand a transformation of polarization vectors.

A answer was found by considering that v is a mode function.Sorry for the trouble.

Hey! I just added a short discussion of the polarization vectors. Basically, you can choose the polarization vectors for the $b$ operators arbitrarily as long as $\vec\epsilon_\lambda^{(b)}(\vec k)\cdot \vec k = 0$ (and $|\epsilon_\lambda(k)| = 1$) and you should be able to recover the commutation relations.
